# Google App Script: How to Store rowcount and modify to update stored rowcount

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

This is what I am trying to achieve with the function propertiesstorage():

1. Store and save row count in property storage in google appscript.
2. Make the stored row counts update with the new rowcounts added. For example 1st stored rowcount === 2000 + 2nd stored rowcount === 2000 = rowcounts 4000 in total.So forth and so on

Code

```
function rowcount()
{ 
 
  var token = getAccessToken();
  var module = "sHistory";
  var rows = 0;
  var go = true;
  var i = 1;
  var data;
  var page = 0;
  
   while (go) {
    Utilities.sleep(20000);
    data = getRecordsByPage(i,200,token,module);
    if (Number(data.info.count) < 200) 
    {
      go = false;
    };
    if ((i%10) == 0) 
    {
       go = false; 
    }
    else if (Number(data.info.page) === true)
    {
      go = true;
      
    }
    page = Number(page) + Number(data.info.page);
    rows = Number(rows) + Number(data.info.count);
    
    //Logger.log("Page " + page);
    //Logger.log("Zoho Recruit Records" + rows);
    i++;
     
   }
      return rows;   
   }

function propertiesstorage()
{

  // saving rowcount in GAS properties
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty("sHistoryRows",rowcount());
  
  //reading rowcount from GAS properties
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var data = scriptProperties.getProperties();

  for(var key in data)
  {
    Logger.log([key,"sHistory total count "+ rowcount()]);
    
  }

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var updatevalue = userProperties.getProperty(rowcount());
  updatevalue = rowcount();
  scriptProperties.setProperty("sHistory total count",updatevalue)
  Logger.log([key,"sHistory total count "+ updatevalue])

}
}
```

This is the reference I am using to try and achieve this - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties

Comment: Please provide [mcve] not your entire code.  I don't want to have to read your entire code

Comment: Hey @Cooper, I updated the code.

Comment: Are the rows added by a user edit?

Comment: I am new to google appscript, I am not sure if its user edit, but this script is running off a spreadsheet. and the rowcount is another function in my code

Comment: Are the rows added by another script or formula or are they added by a human editor?

Comment: the rows are added by the same script, currently, the script calls an API so that I can get access to a list of records, and the row count function counts every 200 records per 1 page. I updated the code up top.

Comment: `var data = scriptProperties.getProperties();` get's the entire scriptProperties object and this `return key,data[rowcount()];` is going to stop the function on the first return and there is no property in data named rowcount() so I don't know what you think you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper. What I am trying to achieve is storing the number of rows counted in the Properties Service feature in google app script. Currently it counts from 2000 - 30000, I know for a fact there are 197 757 records in total it needs to count, so it's fine that it only reaches 30 000 records because the count starts from overs, what I would like is having that every time 30000 is stored its adds another 30000 onto the original one. This ```var data = scriptProperties.getProperties();```, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here? I also did remove the ```return key,data[rowcount()]```

Comment: getProperties() gets the entire script properties object that contains all of the properties.  I mean try getting and looking at it with Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj)) and you should be able to see what I mean.